# How to set JDK instead of JRE as the default JVM on WIndows 7 64bit?

Tags: android, windows-7, java

Im trying to install Android SDK but it says that JRE is not enough and that it needs JDK, I already installed JDK from Oracle website. I'm sure it is installed 'cause I have an eclipse running with the JDK intead of JRE but it was configured manually. How can I make the android SDK installer recognize the JDK?

Comment: Check your CLASSPATH/Path system environment variables. Right-click on "My Computer", select Properties, select the Advanced Settings tab, and click on Environment Variables. I don't have Windows 7, but if I remember correctly, it's still somewhat similar to Windows XP. Also, you could uninstall your original JRE, a JDK will contain one or more JREs, so a JDK is really the only thing you really need.

Answer (score 1):

In win7 64 bit

> drive:\Program files(x86)\java\jdk\bin

copy the whole path and now right click on my computer>properties>advanced tab> environment variables and append the above string to the path after adding semicolon before this line

Comment: I dont have a java folder inside Program Files(x86) and I had tried to do that with the java folder inside the non x86 Program Files and didn't work. I installed the jdk from the Oracle website so I guess it is the last one and the proper one for my system. Thank you for your answer but it seems I still need some help.

Comment: are you sure you installed the JDK not the JRE do install the java again and copy the the destination path with you that will help you later in setting the path

Comment: @norcisa As Axel says you will need the 32-bit version of java as the android sdk does not support 64-bit java.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit applications like Eclipse, visualvm and Andriod SDK will run only on 32-bit JDK regardless on your operating system. So you need to install 32-bit JDK and set your paths to it. It's really frustrating if you have a mix of apps, say, 64bit Eclipse and 32-bit Android :(

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this problem includes several parts:

1. Set HK_LM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion correctly point to the jdk version you installed.
2. Set JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK installed directory.
3. Make %JAVA_HOME%\bin in your PATH environment variable.
4. When calling java, ensure %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\rt.jar is in your class path.
5. And as mentioned by others, 32-bit and 64-bit applications require different versions of JDK.